# Ubuntu and Windows 7 are installed in same Drive, is it safe?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I installed, Ubuntu using windows installer in Windows 7 OS, will it create any problem, if I create partition of same drive.

Comment: No. Not if you do it right.

Comment: Not at all! Adding to @mikewhatever's comment, you can 'do it right' by following the prompts on the wubi.exe installer!

Comment: Windows 7 can shrink the `C:` drive http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx Just make sure you don't switch to 'dynamic' volumes. Don't create new partitions in the space from Windows - if you want to create linux partitions, create them from linux.

Answer (score 5):

> The Windows-based Ubuntu Installer (Wubi) allows you to install and uninstall Ubuntu from within Microsoft Windows. It lets a Microsoft Windows user try Ubuntu without risking any data loss due to disk formatting or partitioning.

<sup>**Source:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi</sup>

No, it wont make any problems, and you are not really creating another partition.

Comment: Actually, I wanna create another partition(Drive), all 450GB is getting used for C: Drive. Please share your idea...

Answer (score -1):

I have both Linux and and 2 installs of Windows 7 (in both 32 and 64-bit versions) installed on my desktop.

The 32-bit version of Windows 7 shares the same physical drive as Linux, but obviously on different partitions. The Windows 7 64-bit version is installed on another drive.

For linux I have 3 partitions:

1. A filesystem partition,
2. A swap partition, and
3. One for data.

I use a utility by diskinternals to manipulate Linux files from within Windows 7.
This setup is quite stable. However, earlier versions showed some problems.

Comment: An "it works for me" comment is not quite an answer in my opinion.